# Boolean acting funky with ridges

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

I'm trying to cut some holes in my trailer for the storage and windows. I try to use a boolean modifier and it doesn't really work. When I try to cut holes in the trailer without the ridges it works okay but then the ridges completely break when I try to add holes in them to match.

Collection 2 is where all these components are held.

Edit 1: I see the normals were flipped on the ridges and that's fixed. The real issue is that the objects are not thick enough to get the boolean to work on them.

Edit 2: I have a working solution. I copied each component, extruded the face then hid it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, boolean objects need to be non-manifold to work correctly. Please share your .blend file following the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ so we can take a look at what you're trying to do

Comment: okay I uploaded it. I'm also having an issue with the shrinkwrap with the vent up top but this is way more pressing. Thanks for helping.

Comment: It should show up on your question above if uploaded correctly... Be sure to use the full URL (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304576/boolean-acting-funky-with-ridges)

Comment: @Dikianify Uploading alone is not enough, you have to edit the code you get after uploading into your question, otherwise we don't know where to get the file.

Comment: I see, thanks for letting me know. It's there now.

Answer (score 0):

First, I went to viewport overlays and selected Face Orientation. In doing so I saw that the ridges had flipped normals. I went to edit mode and hit alt + n, recalculate outside and that fixed that.

Next, I had to block the ridges with a component to actually have boolean remove them. To do that I made a copy of each component and stretched it on its respective axis to block the ridges. I also moved these copies to a new component and had the boolean modifier look at that instead.
[image]

Upon examining these copies with the face orientation, I noticed that some of them had this glitchy double normal on them. Like it had both inside and outside overlapping.

[image]

When I hid all of the components, I saw that the inside normal stuck around.
[image]

I don't know what caused this, but in order to fixed it I had to apply the modifier and delete the extra edges by hand. This means that this process is destructive and I'll have to do it after I finish texturing.[image]

There's gotta be a better way but this worked for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

Comment: @Dikianify That should be ALT-M in your answer, not ALT-N to bring up the normals menu!

Comment: For me it is alt-n, alt-m brings up the split menu.